# How to index for a group by with columns from different tables?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, group-by

Is it possible to create an index from columns of 2 different tables?
If not, how do we optimize a query that does a `group by` on columns of 2 different tables?

For example:  the following statement

```
explain select p.name from Person p join JobStatus js  
group by p.name,js.job_tickets  
order by p.name,p.lastname, pm.job_tickets;
```

Uses indexes if I have for (p.name,p.lastname) and for `job_tickets`.
But I have noticed that on other queries and with more than one joining table the index is omitted.

Comment: This is hard to answer because your query isn't complete... there's no `ON` for the join, and one stray reference to a column from a table with the alias "pm."